# How to create an additional NGNIX ingress controller if there is an existing controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have an existing Nginx controller in my EKS cluster. This is a cluster-wide ingress controller. I want to create another Nginx controller to do some testing. This is also going to be a public-facing ingress controller. Is it possible to do that? I tried creating it by creating a new namespace and then creating new resources under that namespace but it started logging the logs for all the ingresses that were already present. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: have you achieved second controller already?

Comment: No, I haven't. Still looking for a solution. All the documentation that I could find points to having two different ingress controllers or an internal and an external nginx ingress controller but not two public facing nginx ingress controllers side by side.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to investigate and I will let you know. In case you would resolve the issue faster, please let me know.
Additionally I'd appreciate a scenario you need to test and some background on why you need second Ingress instead of editing current ingress parameters.

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the annotation`kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "$INGRESS_CONTROLLER"`

for example here you are saying nginx will be responsible for this ingress

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
```

> if you do not define a class, your cloud provider may use a default ingress controller. 
>   [using-multiple-ingress-controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/#using-multiple-ingress-controllers)

`alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme` annotation is used for deciding internal or public.

List of [ingress Annotation](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller/blob/master/docs/guide/ingress/annotation.md)

Comment: I want to deploy multiple Nginx ingress controllers and both public. I see in the documentation that you can deploy an internal and an external Nginx controller but I don't see any documentation to run two public-facing Nginx controllers side by side.

Comment: https://medium.com/tensult/alb-ingress-controller-on-aws-eks-45bf8e36020d here are some flags which might be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can create additional ingress by deploying nginx ingress image as deployment or daemonset. Below are the manifests for this example. Once you done with this, then you should be able to access the this ingress using nodeIP and nodeport. Then onwards having cloud Loadbalancer that is reachable internal and resolving into node IP's should get you working end to end.

Or you may be better off creating service of type loadbalancer in below example

```
==> config-map.yml <==
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration

==> deployment.yml <==
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-ingress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress
    spec:
      containers:
       - name: nginx-ingress-controller
        image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.21.0
      args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --configmap=${POD_NAMESPACE}/nginx-configuration
      env:
        - name: POD_NAM
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
             fieldPath: metadata.name
        -  name: POD_NAMESPACE
           valueFrom:
             fieldRef:
               fieldPath: metadata.namespace 
      ports:
       - name: http
         containerPort: 80
       - name: https
         containerPort: 443
==> service-account.yml <==
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  - endpoints
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - update
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - create
  - patch
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - "extensions"
  resources:
  - ingresses/status
  verbs:
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - k8s.nginx.org
  resources:
  - virtualservers
  - virtualserverroutes
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - get
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: nginx-ingress
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
==> service.yml <==
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
```